# I break blocks, but can notpick them up

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm mining, I look in my inventory, but not a single block has been picked up. I'm in survival mode, mining stone with a iron pickaxe. Shouldn't I get cobblestone?

Comment: Hmm... Are tiledrops off for some reason? Try going into another world with cheats enabled, give yourself a pickaxe, and try mining there to make sure it's not something particular to that world

Comment: Is `/gamerule doTileDrops true`?

Answer (score 1):

As Unionhawk and aytimothy said, if you have cheats on, then type in `/gamerule doTileDrops true`.

You either have the gamerule set to "False" or have mods installed.