# Tekkit Classic blocks wouldn't drop after being destroyed (single-player)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

Started up tekkit classic version 3.1.2 in single-player, and I was trying to mine. After mining stone blocks repeatedly, with a diamond pickaxe, I noticed that blocks were not dropping. Tried with dirt, still nothing. When I try to drop an item, it also disappears.

I tried deleting Technic Launcher, and re-downloading, and it but I still have the same problem. I am having this problem across all single player worlds.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: While not a duplicate, I believe this [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/230709/i-break-blocks-but-can-notpick-them-up) might be related, and possible answers posted there may be worth trying out. Remember, ***if*** an answer goes up there, and it works for you, rewrite the answer, here. Don't just copy paste it, and reference the author, but this may help other users in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your inventory and click the "Options" button in the bottom left corner. Now, on the right side of the screen there should be a button labeled "Item Drops:Disabled." Click on the button to change it to "Item Drops: Enabled."